# Snap an empty to a bone's coordinate, quickest way?

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, rigid-body-simulation, coordinates

I'm doing a ragdoll system with lots of rigidbody constraints. I use empties as constraints, which will be snapped to the location of a bone.

The problem is that my armature has too many bones and I have a lot of empties to snap to. So is there a quick way to snap a empty to a bone's location?

The possible way I find is to transform snap an empty to a bone's vertex, but somehow the bone's vertex won't be recognized by the snap tool?

Answer (score 1):

I use the procedure described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/168685/111042) to parent an Empty to a bone.  For example set the cursor to a location between a characters eyes; I then add an empty between the eyes (Empty.eyes.rig-dz1), parent that to a face bone to track (might also be able to add Copy Location constraint instead?).  I then have another character whose Eyes have an animated Copy Location (target==empty).  So that when it is enabled, eyes will look the other as the other moves.

Answer (score 1):

First, disable "lock object modes" in main Edit menu.  It will also help if you limit visibility to only the empties and armature you're working with, possibly via a local view ( '/' for me.)

Next, select your armature and enter pose mode.  For each empty: select the appropriate bone, shift select the empty, add copy location constraint.  Adding constraints is easiest when you use the appropriate hotkeys; shift ctrl c -> copy location is the hotkey that works for me.  If another object is selected, creating constraints in this fashion will automatically populate the target of the constraint; if the other object is an armature in pose mode, with an actively selected bone, it will populate the target and bone of the constraint.  Other defaults (notably, world->world space) are appropriate for what you want to do, so there's no need to edit the constraint.

After creating constraints in this fashion, select all of your empties (which is easy if only your armature and empties are visible, as recommended.)  "Apply visual transform" (from 3D object mode's ctrl a menu for me), followed by "Clear object constraints" (which I access via the searchbar.)  Both of these operations can be used on any number of selected objects simultaneously.