# Parenting an object to a bone not working

Tags: animation, objects, armature, bones, parent

I am making a sword attack animation for my character and I want to parent the sword to his right index finger. I read that you have to create an empty, parent the empty to the bone and then parent the sword to the empty. When I tried doing this Blender wouldn't let me parent the empty to a specific bone, only to the whole model. It would also only act as a regular child (following the parents transforms etc.) when I was in object mode. When I tried moving bones in pose mode the sword wouldn't follow. Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct procedure to parent the Empty to the bone is:

1. Select the Empty
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the armature
3. Go to *Pose Mode*
4. Select the bone you need as parent
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose *Bone* option

Comment: this is the correct sequence. still work with blender 2.92. Thanks